# How to call css stylesheets and js files into a custom WordPress theme

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm developing a custom WordPress theme from scratch and now I faced a problem with loading css and js files. I have searched everywhere to see how can I be able to load those files and I did this on my `functions.php` file:

```
    <?php 
function catalog(){
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . 'css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/offcanvas.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','catalog');
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __('Primary Menu'),
    'footer' => __('Footer Menu'),
));
?>
```

So I don't know whats really going wrong here cause I've checked everything and it looks fine. Here's my folder structure:

```
theme_folder
            css
                  bootstrap.min.css
            images
            js
                  bootstrap.min.js
                  imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js
                  jquery.js
                  masonry.pkgd.min.js
                  offcanvas.js
```

But after all this I get this as result which means they have not beed loaded:

[image: print screen]

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong as its been quite sometime sense I worked with WordPress theme's wouldn't you want to use wp_register_script then run wp_enqueue_script? Again this is only off the top of my head, I could be totally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem** You are register a script but not enqueue.

**Solution:**
 If you are register then you have to enqueue.
wp_enqueue_style() - For css enqueue 
wp_enqueue_script()- For JS enqueue

**Updated code**

```
 <?php 
function catalog(){
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-imgesload', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script-offcanvas', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/offcanvas.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','catalog');
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __('Primary Menu'),
    'footer' => __('Footer Menu'),
));
?>
```

**Recommendation**

Always Prefer CDN for css and js like jquery,bootstrap etc.

Comment: You should also use different names, not the same `custom-script` in all `wp_enqueue_script()` calls.

Comment: Yes why not it more preferable

Comment: Else only the last javascript file with that name will be enqueued

Comment: please check again.

Comment: don't remove that style.css.This is theme not plugin.

Comment: oh..sorry..I didn't check that

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

add css file in your template like below...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```